# Unexpected output in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For the below script I am expecting the output to be  `msg_y and msg_z`. But it is printing `msg_x and msg_z`. Can somebody explain to me what is going on?

```
#!/bin/bash
 set -x

vr=2
echo $vr
if [ $vr > 5 ]
then
        echo "entered 1st if"
        echo "msg_x"

        echo "out of 1st if"

        if [ $vr < 8 ]; then
        echo "in of 2nd if"
        echo "msg_y"

        else
        echo "msg_z"
        fi

else
        if [ $vr > 1 ]; then echo "msg_y"

        else echo "msg_z"
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

This expression

```
[ $vr > 5 ]
```

is being parsed as an output redirection; check to see if you have a file named "5" now. The output redirection is vacuously true. Note that the usual admonition to quote parameters inside a test expression would not help here (but it's still a good idea).

You can escape the `>` so that it is seen as an operator in the test command:

```
if [ "$vr" \> 5 ]; then
```

or you can use the integer comparison operator `-gt`

```
if [ "$vr" -gt 5 ]; then.
```

Since you are using `bash`, you can use the more robust
conditional expression

```
if [[ $vr > 5 ]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ $vr -gt 5 ]]; then
```

or use an arithmetic expression

```
if (( vr > 5 )); then
```

to do your comparisions (likewise for the others).

---

Note: although I showed how to make `>` work as a comparison operator even when surrounded by integers, don't do this. Most of the time, you won't get the results you want, since the arguments are compared lexicographically, not numerically. Try `[ 2 \> 10 ] && echo What?` Either use the correct integer comparison operators (`-gt` et al.) or use an arithmetic expression.

Comment: That's a very clear explanation. Appreciate it.

And yes a file called "5" got created.

Comment: It is not correct to say "The output redirection is vacuously true".  The string $vr is non-empty, and that is why `[ $vr > 5 ]` is true.  If `vr` were unset or an empty string, it would be false.